# Entity returns forcing unknown "X"

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vga

My pixel_controller entity, during simulation, acts (I think) correctly but outputs wrongly, more specifically it outputs a std_logic_vector of "forcing unknowns" instead of the right bits.

Terminology:
Charactor: a pixel line of 8 bits of a char font.

I'm developing a VGA controller that prints chracters on screen.
So after writing (copied) a working font_ROM entity (a testbench was made and tested) I started working on the logic that will print the characters stored (for now) in a string; this logic is called Pixel Controller.
My pixel_controller gets signals from the vga_controller and outputs rgb values during screen_enable time.
Important to know is that, for timing constraints, pixel controller asks for charactors vector before they are needed, ex: when charactor N is printed, pixel controller asks to font_ROM for charactor N+1 so that on cicle N+1 this charactor is ready.
When the charactors vectors are requested in the testbench for font_rom all works perfectly but when the same charactors are requested in the implemented font_rom (inside pixel_controller) forcing unknowns are thrown instead, and only for charactors containing at least one 1.

**pixel_controller.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity pixel_controller is
    Generic(
            HORIZONTAL_PIXELS  : INTEGER := 640;
            VERTICAL_PIXELS    : INTEGER := 480;
            ADDR_WIDTH         : INTEGER := 11; -- address width 2^11-1 = addressable memory                  
            DATA_WIDTH         : INTEGER := 8;  -- data width no of pixel reperesenting the character width
            CHAR_WIDTH         : INTEGER := DATA_WIDTH;
            CHAR_HEIGHT        : INTEGER := 16;  
            CHAR_IN_ALPHABET   : INTEGER := 127;
            BITS_ADDRESSING_ALPHABET   : INTEGER := 7; --ln(CHAR_IN_ALPHABET)
            BITS_ADDRESSING_CHAR_HEIGHT: INTEGER := 4; --ln(CHAR_HEIGHT)
    );
    Port ( 
           clk          : in STD_LOGIC;
           resetn       : in STD_LOGIC;
           disp_en      : in STD_LOGIC;
           pixel_col    : in INTEGER;
           pixel_row    : in INTEGER;
           VGA_R        : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
           VGA_G        : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
           VGA_B        : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)
     );
end pixel_controller;

architecture Behavioral of pixel_controller is
    type DATA_ARRAY is array (integer range <>) OF INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 127;
    signal stream : DATA_ARRAY (0 to 127):= ( --its the srteam
        0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
        11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
        21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
        31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
        41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,
        51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,
        61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,
        71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,
        81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,
        91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,
        101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,
        111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,
        121,122,123,124,125,126,127
    );
    signal font_address : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ADDR_WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);
    signal font_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(DATA_WIDTH-1 DOWNTO 0);
    signal char_max_col : INTEGER := HORIZONTAL_PIXELS/data_width; --max number of characters IN A row printable
    signal char_max_row : INTEGER := VERTICAL_PIXELS/data_width; --max number of text rows printable 

    signal char_VGA_col: INTEGER RANGE 0 TO HORIZONTAL_PIXELS/data_width; -- since we think in characters it's usefull to know in witch character column we are
    signal char_VGA_row : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO VERTICAL_PIXELS/data_width; -- since we think in characters it's usefull to know in witch character row we are

begin
    f_rom: entity work.fonts_rom(Behavioral)
    port map(
        clk =>clk,
        addr=>font_address,
        data_out => font_out
    );

    char_VGA_col <= pixel_col/CHAR_WIDTH; --with this we know in witch character colum we are
    char_VGA_row <= pixel_row/CHAR_HEIGHT; --with this we know on which line of text we are                                         
  GET_FUT_PIX_VAL: process (resetn,char_VGA_col) is    -- at clock N get the pixel value for process N+1
                                                    -- the process depends on the char_VGA_Col since 
                                                    -- char_VGA_row cannot change previously to it    
    variable requested_character : INTEGER := 0; -- character obtained by stream 
    variable charactor_line : INTEGER:= 0; -- which line of pixels of a specific character is requested
    begin
        if resetn = '0' then   -- async reset
            font_address <= (others => '0'); 
            font_out <= (others =>'0');
            requested_character := 0;
            charactor_line := 0;
         elsif char_VGA_col /= char_VGA_col'LAST_VALUE then -- if actual value is different then the previous one
                                                           -- process starts every CHAR_WIDTH pixel printed
           if(char_VGA_col + char_max_col*char_VGA_row < 126) -- my string contains 127 chars

            requested_character := stream(char_max_col*char_VGA_row + char_VGA_col + 1); -- note the + 1: the requested value is for the future pixel_col
                                                                                         -- the value will be accessible at a clk delay (not VGA_CLK)
            charactor_line := pixel_row MOD CHAR_HEIGHT; -- which charactor line of the character we are printing

            font_address <=  std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(requested_character,BITS_ADDRESSING_ALPHABET))
                            & std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(charactor_line,BITS_ADDRESSING_CHAR_HEIGHT));                          

           end if;     -- NB values will be requested even during the back porch pulse and front porch of v_sync
        end if;
    end process;
   PRINT_PIXEL: process (pixel_col) is -- pixel_col is effectively the same as CLK TODO:see if the latency is problematic
   begin
        if (font_out( (pixel_col)  MOD CHAR_WIDTH ) = '0' AND disp_en = '1') then -- HERE COULD BE PRINTED ALL IN REVERS ORDER LOOK AT HOW FONT_OUT IS DEFINED
            VGA_R <= (others => '1'); -- inverse coloring: white on black
            VGA_G <= (others => '1');
            VGA_B <= (others => '1');
        else 
            VGA_R <= (others => '0');
            VGA_G <= (others => '0');
            VGA_B <= (others => '0');
        end if;
   end process;
```

**testbench_pixel_controller.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;
use work.commonPak.ALL;

entity pixel_controller_testbench is
--  Port ( );
end pixel_controller_testbench;

architecture Behavioral of pixel_controller_testbench is
    component clk_wiz_0 is --takes 100MHZ and returns 25MHz 
    port(
        clk_in1 : in STD_LOGIC;
        resetn  : in STD_LOGIC;
        CLK_VGA : out STD_LOGIC
    );
    end component;
    component pixel_controller is
    Generic(
            HORIZONTAL_PIXELS  : INTEGER := 640;
            VERTICAL_PIXELS    : INTEGER := 480;
            ADDR_WIDTH         : INTEGER := 11;     
            DATA_WIDTH         : INTEGER := 8;
            CHAR_WIDTH         : INTEGER := DATA_WIDTH;
            CHAR_HEIGHT        : INTEGER := 16;  
            CHAR_IN_ALPHABET   : INTEGER := 127;
            BITS_ADDRESSING_ALPHABET   : INTEGER := 7; --ln(CHAR_IN_ALPHABET)
            BITS_ADDRESSING_CHAR_HEIGHT: INTEGER := 4; --ln(CHAR_HEIGHT)
    ); 
    port(
        clk         : in STD_LOGIC;
        resetn      : in STD_LOGIC;
        disp_en     : in STD_LOGIC;
        pixel_col   : in INTEGER;
        pixel_row   : in INTEGER;
        VGA_R       : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        VGA_G       : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        VGA_B       : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)
    );
    end component;
    component vga_controller is 
    generic(
        h_pulse         : INTEGER   :=96;       
        h_bkprch        : INTEGER   :=48;       
        h_pixels        : INTEGER   :=640;      
        h_frprch        : INTEGER   :=16;       
        h_pol           : STD_LOGIC :='0';      

        v_pulse         : INTEGER   :=2;        
        v_bkprch        : INTEGER   :=33;       
        v_pixels        : INTEGER   :=480;      
        v_frprch        : INTEGER   :=10;       
        v_pol           : STD_LOGIC :='1'       
        );
    port(
        pixel_clk   : in STD_LOGIC;
        res         : in STD_LOGIC;
        h_sync      : out STD_LOGIC;
        v_sync      : out STD_LOGIC;
        disp_en     : out STD_LOGIC;
        column      : out INTEGER;
        row         : out INTEGER
    );
    end component;
    signal CLK100HZ,CPU_RESETN,VGA_HS,VGA_VS,CLK_25,disp_en : STD_LOGIC;
    signal column,row : INTEGER;
    signal VGA_R,VGA_G,VGA_B : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
begin
    clk_wiz: clk_wiz_0 port map(
        clk_in1 => CLK100HZ,
        resetn  => CPU_RESETN,
        CLK_VGA =>CLK_25
    );
    vga_c: vga_controller port map(
        pixel_clk   => CLK_25,
        res         => CPU_RESETN,
        h_sync      => VGA_HS,
        v_sync      => VGA_VS,
        disp_en     => disp_en,
        column      => column,
        row         => row
    );
    px_ctrl: pixel_controller port map(
        clk         => CLK100HZ,
        resetn      => CPU_RESETN,
        disp_en     => disp_en,
        pixel_col   => column,
        pixel_row   => row,
        VGA_R       => VGA_R,
        VGA_G       => VGA_G,
        VGA_B       => VGA_B
    );


    CLK:process begin
        CLK100HZ <= '0';
        wait for 5ns;
        CLK100HZ <= '1';
        wait for 5ns;
    end process;

    process begin
        CPU_RESETN <= '0';
        wait for 15ns;
        CPU_RESETN <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

VGA_controller.vhd and font_ROM.vhd (ASCII) are files that are "always" the same everywhere.

On pixel 56 of first row, charactor value number 07 must be displayed and charactor value number 08 must be requested. The request is performed and after a clk the value should be "11111111" aka xff instead a bunch of "X" is what i get.

Here a visualization of the sequence
- clk100 is the system clk whith which font requests are made
- clk25 is the VGA clk with which pixels are drawn.
[image: testbench timeline]

Comment: You're post doesn't present a [mcve]. There does appear however to be (at least) two drivers for `font_out`. One in process `GET_FUT_PIX_VAL` and one `f_rom: entity work.fonts_rom(Behavioral` should `font_out` actually be assigned there (and that can't be determined without a [mcve]).

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.2 Drivers "Every signal assignment statement in a process statement defines a set of *drivers* for certain scalar signals. There is a single driver for a given scalar signal S in a process statement, provided that there is at least one signal assignment statement in that process statement and that the longest static prefix of the target signal of that signal assignment statement denotes S or denotes a composite signal of which S is a subelement. Each such signal assignment statement is said to be *associated* with that driver. ..."

Comment: Hi @user1155120 I know that my post does not represent an mre but for making it complete several long files should be added. Those files nevertheless are similar between all of them and retrivable on line, so do you think that linking some examples of them will be fine?

Comment: @user1155120 for what concerns the double driver, I don't know if this is the case: `f_rom` and `GET_FUT_PIX_VAL` use `font_addr` and `font_out`, but `font_addr` is only written by `GET_FUT.. ` and `font_out` is resetted by `GET_FUT` and written by `f_rom`, is this a case of doble driver? Or maybe is the fact that `GET_FUT` reads it?

Comment: @JhonathanAsimov font_out is connected to the ouput of fonts_rom and assigned to 0 in the reset of the process. Hence multiple drivers where X will result. Remove it from the reset.